# Imghdr module in Python 3.9.5 misidentifying .png file

Tags: python-3.x, imghdr

When I call `imghdr.what(sampleImage.png)` it recognizes it as a `jpeg` for some reason. For example if I use `print(imghdr.what(sampleImage.png))` it will output the string `"jpeg"`. I checked the image file and it is displayed as having the expected `PNG` file format on `Mac OSX`.

Comment: I suspect it truly actually is jpeg data inside a file incorrectly named `.png`. I don't know how you "checked" it, but most software will probably just display the jpeg image despite the file extension.

Comment: If you want help, you'll have to find a way to post `sampleImage.png` for us to look at.